# How to use PHP variable inside a modal ajax window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Main Page (`main.php`) contains the variable:

`$var = "hello"`

A Modal window (`modal.php`) is being loaded using AJAX, with this script:

```
var modal_xhr = $.ajax({
            'type'      : 'GET',
            'dataType'  : 'html',
            'url'       : modal.php,
            'data'      : []
        })
```

And I want to echo `$var` inside `modal.php`.

I guess session is one way to do it, but it doesn't sound appropriate.

Perhaps something inside the `data` field? I'm not sure how to modify it, what does the current `[]` means?

Or maybe another method to do this?

Comment: You can return data to the data field by changing `[]` to a `function(data) {}`. Return the data as a json encoded string

Answer (score 0):

Certinaly you can use `data` attribute to pass the variable through AJAX call.

Pass the variable like this,

```
$.ajax({
    'type'      : 'GET',
    'dataType'  : 'html',
    'url'       : modal.php,
    'data'      : {'hello':'<?php echo $var ?>'}
});
```

Current `[]` means you're not passing any values through AJAX call.

As it's as `GET` request you can use this variable on **modal.php** with `$_GET`, in case of `POST` type use `$_POST`.

```
{'hello':'<?php echo $var ?>'}
```

In above syntax, `hello` is the key and it's value is on the right side.

Comment: The PHP code doesn't compile, maybe because the JS is an external file and not inline in `main.php` page, what should I do?

Comment: Yes to use `<?php echo $var ?>` JS code must be inside **.php** page.

Comment: Any other ways to achieve what I want then? Maybe session is the best option..?

Comment: No other ways to pass the `PHP variable` to `JS` without putting JS code on the same page.

Comment: @AlokPatel, it can be inside $.ajax's response's .success() function.

Comment: @LajosArpad `$var` is on **main.php** file, JS code must be on the same page to use it via `PHP`.

Comment: @AlokPatel, he can request main.php as well. I wanted to clarify this in general terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as a **GET** parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    'type'      : 'GET',
    'dataType'  : 'html',
    'url'       : 'modal.php?myvar=<?php echo $var; ?>'
});
```

You can send it as a **POST** parameter as well:

```
$.ajax({
    'type'      : 'GET',
    'dataType'  : 'html',
    'url'       : 'modal.php',
    data: {myvar: "<?php echo $var; ?>"}
});
```

At PHP-level you can use `$_GET["myvar"]` or `$_POST["myvar"]` inside your echo. Server response can be used in the `.success()` `function` of the result of `$.ajax()`.